# Laravel eloquent multiple table join with filter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

There are theree tables in my system.

1. Students
2. Articles
3. categories

Student can write many articles and a article is belong to just one student. And A Article can have only one category.

**Controller**

```
public function all_articles_by_student_by_category(Request $request){


        $students_id = $request->students_id;
        $categories_id = $request->categories_id;


        $article_list = Students::find($students_id)->articles->all();

        //This return Something like, Select All Articles Written by Damith
    }
```

**Model**

```
class Students extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id','first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Articles');
    }
}
```

**What I am try to get**

Something like, Select All Articles Written by Damith for Technology Category (Category Name should be there)

**What I able to do so far**

Something like, Select All Articles Written by Damith using `$article_list = Students::find($students_id)->articles->all();` (You can find this code from controller)

**What I want from you**

How do I modify `$article_list = Students::find($students_id)->articles->all();` to get, something like, Select All Articles Written by Damith for Technology Category. (**Category name must be there in result and it is on category table, and for where condtion you can use the category_id which is i  the article table** )

Comment: The answer is easy, please checkout the Laravel documentation on how to use eloquent. If you are able to do a plain SQL query this means that you are able to do it with eloquent. Just learn the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off with **what you have done so far** the `->all()` method is not needed when getting the records for a relation on a model, this would return all of the articles linked to that student:

```
Students::find($students_id)->articles
```

---

**Go through Articles Model**
You could do something like:

```
Article::where('student_id', $students_id)
  ->where('category_id', $category_id)->get();
```

Which would acheive the result you are after.

---

**Go through Students Model**

If you want to go through `Students` `Model` you can constrain the relation using the `with` method.

```
$student = Students::with(['articles' => function($query) use ($category_id) {
  $query->where('category_id', $category_id);
}])->find($student_id);

$filteredArticles = $student->articles
```

---

**Useful Links**

- Laravel Docs 5.5 for `Eager Loading` : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

> When accessing Eloquent relationships as properties, the relationship data is "lazy loaded". This means the relationship data is not actually loaded until you first access the property. However, Eloquent can "eager load" relationships at the time you query the parent model.

- Laravel Docs 5.5 for `Constraining Eager Loads`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

> Sometimes you may wish to eager load a relationship, but also specify additional query constraints for the eager loading query.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am reading this and `Article::where('student_id', $students_id)
  ->where('category_id', $category_id)->get();` worked fine. . I thought this return  just `select * from articles where student_id=2 and categories_id=3`.......... Now my question is how Laravel knows article table and category table should join just `where('category_id', '=', $categories_id)` line?

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. You need to fully explain what help you want now. See Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson You may want to try out the `Go through Students Model` method if you want to still have the data for the student.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
$technologyArticles = Articles::where('student_id', '=', $students_id)->where('category_id', '=', $categories_id)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I thought this return  just `select * from articles where student_id=2 and categories_id=3`.......... Now my question is how Laravel knows article table and category table should joing just `where('category_id', '=', $categories_id)` line?

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. You need to fully explain what help you want now. See Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships